# texstudio editor on external monitor shows text scambled

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, latex

The editor shows the text on my external monitor as scrambled almost as if the text is written over each other, the line the cursor is on shows normal though, and in a smaller font. Everything displays fine on my laptop's own screen. I am using Windows 10. Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on desktop, go to Display then you see the a slider with a heading  saying, Change the size of text....
Move the slider to where it's appropriate
and you are good to go.

Changing display props. of a specific app:
You can right click the text editor or whatever software is not responding, go to properties then compatibility. Below you will find some DPI settings.You should change the High DPI scaling override to be performed by the system.  Everything will be running fine now.

For TEXwork users go to Edit>>Preferences>>Preview tab
Over there you will find Screen resolution value in dpi. Now bring a real ruler  and match the one shown on the screen and adjust dpi value so that one inch in the screen is one inch in reality. Then you are good to go.
[image: Here you can enter the dpi of your monitor]

Okay my cousin had TexStudio on his machine and I would suggest you to go to Options>>Cofigure>>Internal PDF Viewer and set the dpi value according to that on the box of your new monitor.This is very similar to what I did in TeXworks.

Comment: I suggest you to keep the text open while you adjust the slider

Comment: That works, although I was hoping for something that won't change the settings for all my other applications as well, not really a fan of oversized text on my external monitor.

Comment: I can of course help you with that too.

Comment: I have edited the answer, mark it as an answer if it helps.

Comment: Oky that works took some trial and error, perhaps just adjust your answer to say specifically to say you should change the High DPI scaling override to be performed by the system.  I will mark ist as answered.

Comment: Did exactly as you asked to

Comment: I have come with a far better solution if you use TEXworks

Comment: I can't verify the TEXworks solution but the other worked for TEXstudio, thank you

Comment: See I have updated for the TexStudio solution